# Plotting two 3D lines causes FE crash

Tags: graphics3d, crash

The code below causes the Front End to **CRASH**.  I came across this problem in some code that is very complicated, so I narrowed down the problem to a very simple task, to plot a couple of lines.

```
(* WARNING: CAUSES CRASH *)
Block[{p0 = {2, 0, 0}, seed = 2, n = 11},
 SeedRandom[seed];
 Graphics3D[{Line@
    Table[p + 3 {-0.5 + Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.5 t}
     , {p, p0 + # & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}][[-2 ;;]]}
     , {t, -4, 4}]}
  (* no bug if PlotRange->Automatic *)
  , PlotRange -> ({# - 4.2, # + 4.2} & /@ p0)
  ]
 ]
```

Here's my version/system info

```
"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"
```

Questions:

1. Are there any workarounds?
2. On which systems does this problem arise?

Reported to WRI: [CASE:5121211]

*Update:*
WRI responded with an even simpler example of the bug, which can also be avoid by using the `"BSPTree"` rendering engine:

```
Graphics3D[
 Line[{{{0, 0, -6}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, -3, 6}},{{0, 3, -6}, {-3,0,-3}}}],
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2},{-2, 2}, {-2, 4}}]
```

Comment: fyi, on V 14 on windows 10, all of Mathematica crashes and closes. Not just the front end. Using V 13.3.1 on same PC, no crash and no problems. (ps. added missing `]` at end  of code)

Comment: The code works fine on Mma 12.2 Windows 7

Comment: Works fine on 11.3,12.2,12.3,13.3.1 but not 14.0

Answer (score 3):

I've found two workarounds, using a different rendering engine and mapping `Line[]` over the list of lists of coordinates. The first seems easiest to me from a programming viewpoint, especially if the bug is ever fixed.

```
Block[{p0 = {2, 0, 0}, seed = 2, n = 11},
 SeedRandom[seed];
 Graphics3D[{Line@
    Table[p + 3 {-0.5 + Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.5 t}
     , {p, p0 + # & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}][[-2 ;;]]}
     , {t, -4, 4}]}
  (* no bug if PlotRange->Automatic *)
  , PlotRange -> ({# - 4.2, # + 4.2} & /@ p0)
  (* FIX: Graphics3DRenderingEngine *)
  , BaseStyle -> 
   RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]
 ]

Block[{p0 = {2, 0, 0}, seed = 2, n = 11},
 SeedRandom[seed];
 Graphics3D[{Line /@ (* <-- FIX: Map *)
    Table[p + 3 {-0.5 + Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.5 t}
     , {p, p0 + # & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}][[-2 ;;]]}
     , {t, -4, 4}]}
  (* no bug if PlotRange->Automatic *)
  , PlotRange -> ({# - 4.2, # + 4.2} & /@ p0)
  ]
 ]
```

I tried rewriting it as `GraphicsComplex`, but it crashed my front end.